# Reflection of getUrl method in Magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

If I change getUrl method of AbstractTemplate.php, how much effect on other template in Magento 2.1.12. I am doing this for redirect custom forgotpassword page in Angular frontend. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is if you change it in the abstract class, it'll affect every class that extends from that abstract class.

The class `\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate` is extended by three classes:

- `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template`
- `\Magento\Email\Model\Template`
- `\Magento\Email\Model\BackendTemplate`

So it will affect any email template which uses those three instances.

Having said, I would council against modifying the abstract class.

Magento 2 provides much better options to modify functionality, e.g. Plugins. In the Magento 2 context, Plugins are methods which can be called before, during or after any method call where the method has public visibility.

That is a much more future-proof way of implementing your own custom logic.